# laravel group data from different tables with better performance

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am using the [kalnoy nestedset](https://packagist.org/packages/kalnoy/nestedset) package to have my users in tree form. I wanted to generate some report from other tables and group by the 1st layer of children in my users table.

Users

```
--------------------------------------------------
| id | name        | role_id |     parent_id     |
--------------------------------------------------
|  1 |   master    |     1   |          1        |
|  2 |   child1    |     3   |          1        |
|  3 |   child2    |     3   |          1        |
|  4 |   normal1   |     4   |          2        |
|  5 |   normal2   |     4   |          2        |
|  6 |  child1und1 |     3   |          2        |
|  7 |  child1und2 |     3   |          2        |
|  8 |  child2und1 |     3   |          3        |
|  9 |  child2und2 |     3   |          3        |
| 10 |   normal3   |     4   |          8        |
| 11 |   normal4   |     4   |          7        |
| 12 |   normal5   |     4   |          9        |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Summaries

```
-----------------------------------------------
| id |   value  |    type |       user_id     |
-----------------------------------------------
|  1 |     1    |     1   |          2        |
|  2 |    10    |     1   |          4        |
|  3 |    40    |     2   |          4        |
|  4 |    80    |     3   |         10        |
|  5 |    80    |     3   |         11        |
-----------------------------------------------
```

Stores

```
-----------------------------------------------
| id |   value  |    type |       user_id     |
-----------------------------------------------
|  1 |     4    |     1   |          2        |
|  2 |    12    |     1   |          4        |
|  3 |    55    |     3   |          4        |
|  4 |    90    |     3   |         10        |
|  5 |    42    |     3   |         11        |
-----------------------------------------------
```

I always wanted to sum up my selected user with its children where `role_id = 4` and then list down its children with `role_id = 3` and sum up all their descendants where `role_id = 4`. For instance, if the selected user is "child1", the list will be:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   username  | sum_type_1 | sum_type_2 | sum_type_3 | store_type_1 | store_type_3 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    child1   |     11     |     40     |      0     |      16      |      55      |
|  child1und1 |      0     |      0     |      0     |       0      |       0      |
|  child1und2 |      0     |      0     |     80     |       0      |      42      |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Below is the code that I have tried, the looping makes my function take very long to run as my data can be very large.

```
public function testReport()
{
    $parent = User::find($parentId);

    $allPlayers = $parent->descendants;
    $playerIds = $allPlayers->where('role_id', 4)->pluck('id');

    $sumType1 = collect();
    $sumType1Cols = Summaries::whereIn('user_id', $playerIds)->chunk(5000, function ($sumType1Cols) use ($sumType1) {
        foreach ($sumType1Cols as $sumType1Col) {
            $sumType1->push($sumType1Col);
        }
    });
    
    $sumType2 = collect();
    $sumType2Cols = Summaries::whereIn('user_id', $playerIds)->chunk(5000, function ($sumType2Cols) use ($sumType2) {
        foreach ($sumType2Cols as $sumType2Col) {
            $sumType2->push($sumType2Col);
        }
    });
    
    $sumType3 = collect();
    $sumType3Cols = Summaries::whereIn('user_id', $playerIds)->chunk(5000, function ($sumType3Cols) use ($sumType3) {
        foreach ($sumType3Cols as $sumType3Col) {
            $sumType3->push($sumType3Col);
        }
    });

    $storeType1 = collect();
    $storeType1Cols = Stores::whereIn('user_id', $playerIds)->chunk(5000, function ($storeType1Cols) use ($storeType1) {
        foreach ($storeType1Cols as $storeType1Col) {
            $storeType1->push($storeType1Col);
        }
    });

    $storeType3 = collect();
    $storeType3Cols = Stores::whereIn('user_id', $playerIds)->chunk(5000, function ($storeType3Cols) use ($storeType3) {
        foreach ($storeType3Cols as $storeType3Col) {
            $storeType3->push($storeType3Col);
        }
    });
   
    $userArr = array();
    $userCollection = collect();
    $reportArray = array();

    $res = $this->newPassUserToGetRecord($parent->children->where('role_id', 4), $sumType1, $sumType2, $sumType3, $storeType1, $storeType3);
    $userArr = [
        'id' => $parent->id,
        'username' => $parent->username,
        'name' => $parent->name,
        'res' => $res,
    ];

    if ($userArr) {
        $userCollection->push($userArr);
    }
    $userArr = array();

    $childAgents = $parent->children->where('role_id', 3);
    foreach ($childAgents as $childAgent) {
        $reportArray = array();
        $res = $this->newPassUserToGetRecord($parent->children->where('role_id', 4), $sumType1, $sumType2, $sumType3, $storeType1, $storeType3);
        $userArr = [
            'id' => $childAgent->id,
            'username' => $childAgent->username,
            'name' => $childAgent->name,
            'res' => $res,
            'np' => $np
        ];
        $userCollection->push($userArr);
    }

    return response()->json([
        'userCollection' => $userCollection,
    ]);
}

public function newPassUserToGetRecord($players, $sumType1, $sumType2, $sumType3, $storeType1, $storeType3)
{
    $sumType1Total = 0;
    $sumType2Total = 0;
    $sumType3Total = 0;
    $storeType1Total = 0;
    $storeType3Total = 0;

    $sumType1Result = $sumType1->whereIn('user_id', $players->plucks('id'))->sum('amount');
    $sumType1Total += $sumType1Result;
   
    $sumType2Result = $sumType2->whereIn('user_id', $players->plucks('id'))->sum('amount');
    $sumType2Total += $sumType2Result;
   
    $sumType3Result = $sumType3->whereIn('user_id', $players->plucks('id'))->sum('amount');
    $sumType3Total += $sumType3Result;
    
    $storeType1Result = $storeType1->whereIn('user_id', $players->plucks('id'))->sum('amount');
    $storeType1Total += $storeType1Result;
    
    $storeType3Result = $storeType3->whereIn('user_id', $players->plucks('id'))->sum('amount');
    $storeType3Total += $storeType3Result;

    $reportArray['sumType1']['total'] = $sumType1Total;
    $reportArray['sumType2']['total'] = $sumType2Total;
    $reportArray['sumType3']['total'] = $sumType3Total;
    $reportArray['storeType1']['total'] = $storeType1Total;
    $reportArray['storeType3']['total'] = $storeType3Total;

    return $reportArray;
}
```

I hope for a better approach to improve performance because I am ending up having more types and more data.

Comment: Weirdly, this looks more like an edge/adjaceny list than a nested set

Comment: I called it nested is because on the 2nd level children and i will sum all their descendants value. Any idea to improve the performance like use query or eloquent with lesser loop?